# Carbon for Laravel is not displaying the day name

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

glad to be here

I am currently taking a deeper look into Laravel and found a class (Carbon - Time formatting) that is interesting for me. But now I've got the problem, that the German day name is not displayed. If I switch the locale to English its gonna be displayed.

In my index.blade.php

```
{{dd(Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y'))}}
```

and it returns: `b"Donnerstag 29 März 2018"`

and if I remove the dd() it won't be displayed anymore. Maybe someone knows a solution to solve this problem.

Best regards,
RobDeFlop

Comment: What's the result of `{{ Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') }}`? Nothing?

Comment: Yes, actually it is displaying nothing

Comment: What about `{!! Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') !!}`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. Its working now.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.6?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest Laravel (5.6)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am currently working on my home server with Windows 10 and XAMPP but in the future, I will transfer it to a Linux VPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Windows issue. Add this to your code:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setUtf8(true);
```

Then `{{ Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') }}` works.
You shouldn't use `{!! ... !!}` for that.

Comment: Yeah this is working but it seems like it doesn't support UTF it shows:
" Freitag 30 MÃ¤rz 2018"

Comment: I can reproduce your problem on Windows but `setUtf8()` fixes it for me.

Comment: Are you using it in an HTML document with `<meta charset="utf-8">`?

Comment: Sure, I am using it. But I found my mistake. I had `\Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');` in my AppServicesProviders.php

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link:

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Try this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');      // Mittwoch 21 Mai 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'English');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');      // Wednesday 21 May 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, ''); // reset locale
```